# samba smbstatus logging all not just current connections

Tags: samba

using `smbstatus` that reports on **current** connections.
Is there a way to save, or have, the information reported from `smbstatus` for **ALL** samba connections that have happened over some period of time?

Specifically, the columns of **UID**, **SharePath**, **Name**, **Time** reported by smbstatus I would like to have every one of those at least.

And ideally, for each of those samba connections is there a way to know the hostname or ip address it came from?

**update:**

so I think all I need is in `smb.conf` under `[global]`

- log level = 3 passdb:5 auth:5

I am then able to find relevant info in `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` such as

- Got user=[*my username*]
- workstation=[*my computer name*]
- Allowed connection from *ip address* (*ip address*)

**any help regarding `passdb:#` and `auth:#` would be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

The commands configured in the `preexec` and `postexec` options of Samba are run when a connection to a share is made and disconnected. You could use that to create log entries of those events.

Such simple logging could be achieved by adding this to the `global` section of your smb.conf file:

```
preexec = /usr/bin/logger -t smbd 'connecting to %S on %L by %u at %m os %a using %R ip %I'
postexec = /usr/bin/logger -t smbd 'disconnect of %S on %L by %u at %m'
```

Example output:

```
Oct 31 13:14:55 dev smbd: connecting to stuff on dev by roel at 192.168.30.1 os Samba using SMB3_11 ip 192.168.30.1
Oct 31 13:15:03 dev smbd: disconnect of stuff on dev by roel at 192.168.30.1
```

Note that these logs will most likely wind up in syslog or messages, depending on how your system is configured.